# Return rows only if second column is different

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a Customer number and a country. I need to return all customers that have different countries entered against each of them. That is, do not show me customers where the country values against them is the same for all records.

In the example below:

```
╔══════════╦═════════╗
║ Customer ║ Country ║
╠══════════╬═════════╣
║      123 ║ USA     ║
║      123 ║ USA     ║
║      123 ║ UK      ║
║      456 ║ USA     ║
║      456 ║ USA     ║
║      789 ║ FRA     ║
║      789 ║ FRA     ║
║      789 ║ FRA     ║
╚══════════╩═════════╝
```

should return:

```
╔══════════╗
║ Customer ║
╠══════════╣
║      123 ║
╚══════════╝
```

Comment: `group by` and `having` should solve that fairly easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  do this  by `COUNT(DISTINCT)` and `group by`

```
select Customer
from (
  select 
    Customer,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Country) cnt
  from my_table
  group by Customer
) x
where cnt > 1
```

[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0bdec/2)

adding `having` can  remove the subquery

```
select 
Customer
from my_table
group by Customer
having COUNT(DISTINCT Country) > 1
```

[sql  fiddle  demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0bdec/3)

Answer (score 0):

I think CTE will solves your problem

```
with a(customer,country ,rank)
as
(
select  customer,country , rank() over(partition by  a order by b)  as rank from table
 )

select distinct customer from a
where rank>1
```